# How to time the different parts of a jQuery AJAX request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am wanting the ability to time the different parts of a jQuery ajax command.  Specifically I want to know:

1. How long does it take to send the request to the server
2. How long is the wait before any data is sent back (whilst the server is processing the request).
3. How long does the response take before it fully arrives on the client

So as an example, if an ajax call takes 3 seconds. I would like to be able to say 0.25 seconds is sending the request, 2 seconds waiting, 0.75 seconds receiving the response.

I want to be able to get this information from code so that it can be audited in a database.

I have been looking at the `XMLHttpRequest` object and `onreadystatechange` but the events fired do not seem to relate the sections I am wanting to time.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is. Even if there were events for the things you wish to time, due to the asynchronous nature of how those callbacks are implemented, it would be highly dependent on the client side environment. You might be able to get some of that information from your webserver software's logs.